# Quickly finding the smallest subset of vectors that span a given set of vectors in Julia

Tags: performance, julia, linear-algebra

I have two sets of n x 1 linearly independent vectors, spanning_vectors and correct_vectors. I want to find the smallest subset of spanning_vectors that still spans all vectors in correct_vectors.

I used two separate functions to find the smallest subset, going through every vector in spanning_vectors and only adding it to the vectors_to_return if spanning_vectors could not span correct_vectors without it. Here is the code:

```
function spans(vectors1::Vector{Vector{Int64}}, vectors2::Vector{Vector{Int64}}) :: Bool
    return rank(hcat(hcat(vectors1...), hcat(vectors2...))) == rank(hcat(vectors1...))
end

function smallest_subset(spanning_vectors:: Vector{Vector{Int64}}, correct_vectors:: Vector{Vector{Int64}}) :: Vector{Vector}
    vectors_to_return = Vector{Vector}()
    for (index, vector) in enumerate(spanning_vectors)
        if (!spans(spanning_vectors[1:end .!= index], correct_vectors))
            push!(vectors_to_return, vector)
        end
    end
    return vectors_to_return
end
```

However, this code is extremely slow, and is a bottleneck of my program, since I am calling this function upwards of 10k times. Is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: Perhaps more of a pure math question, what strategy to use for this, regardless of language. For example, `rank(hcat(vectors1...)) == length(vectors1)`  since they are linearly independent. Something clever like this that would avoid computing the costly (and inexact) `rank`  repeatedly though I am to stupid to figure out anything better right now.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly the requirements, the following function returns the indices in `spanning_vectors` which span the `correct_vectors` subspace. The method relies on QR factorization which, in turn, does Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. The idea is to find the orthogonal space using `spanning_vectors`, and the rest of the `spanning_vectors` should cover the span of the `correct_vectors`:

```
function smallest_subset(spanning_vectors, correct_vectors)
    # add checks for correct inputs (dimension-wise, etc.)
    eps = 1.0e-10
    r = qr(hcat(correct_vectors..., spanning_vectors...)).R
    K,L,D = length.((correct_vectors, 
                     spanning_vectors,
                     correct_vectors[1]))
    unused = Set{Int}()
    for i in 1:D
        t = findfirst(j->abs(r[i,j]) > eps && 
                         j ∉ unused, 1:K+L)
        t > K && push!(unused, t)
    end
    return setdiff(K+1:K+L, unused).-K
end
```

Note that I removed some of the typing from both arguments and function return. In Julia these are mostly identified from types at function invocation which allow the compiler to infer the return type.

Also note, `eps` might need to be modified depending on numerical errors during `qr` decomposition and the numerical properties of  the vectors.